# how do I connect a socket to a modem connection?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, modem

All,

I am working on an embedded linux application that is to use a cellular connection to communicate with a database.

I know that I can use AT commands to create socket to the server, but how do I get access to the socket from a C++ program?  That is, after I issue the AT commands, how do I use it from an application?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't find an answer...

Thanks for all your help!

:bp:

Comment: If you're referring to TCP/IP sockets, it's going to take a lot more than issuing commands to the modem.

Comment: I can send AT+WIPCREATE command to the modem to create a socket, but how do I use it from a C program (that wrote to the /dev/ttyUSB0 to send the command) to write data out that socket and read data from that socket?

Comment: Sorry, I'd never heard of WIPCREATE before. No idea how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for your modem.  Multitech has one online [here](http://www.multitech.com/en_US/documents/collateral/manuals/s000437e.pdf) for their modems which may or may not be helpful (if yours is compatible).

Generally, after doing the WIPCREATE, you need to wait for a WIPREADY or WIPACCEPT from the modem; you can then do WIPDATA to put your connection to the modem into data mode, at which point everything you write will be sent to the socket, and anything received on the socket will be sent back to you (so you can treat the fd connected to the modem as if it was a socket, you just need to be careful not to send escape sequences accidentally -- or at least escape the escape sequences properly).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your OS. On most normal Unix OS's you can simply use /dev/tty*, open it, set the baudrate etc and issue AT commands.

Comment: That of course assumes you are using a serial link to your modem :)

Comment: yes, but to send data do I write to the tty? If not preceded by AT is it considered data?